# jquery ajax success redirect as a variable url

Tags: jquery, ajax

On a successful ajax call I would like to refresh the current page the user is on. I have tried below but nothing happens.  Looking at chrome debug I see no errors, nor any network activity.

```
get[1] = "module=ticket&ticketId=12345#"
```

I have tried:

```
success:function(result){
             var url = location.href;
             var get = url.split("?");
             alert(get[1]);
             window.location.href = "index.php?"+get[1];
        }
```

as well as:

```
success:function(result){
             location.href = location.href;
        }
```

and:

```
success:function(result){
             var url = location.href;
             var get = url.split("?");
             var myUrl = "index.php?"+get[1];
             window.location.href =myUrl;
        }
```

Comment: does it reach the success block? add the "error" handler in your ajax call as well see if the response is redirected there

Comment: yea, its successful, i threw an alert as last line of success function and i get the alert. @smarx has correct answer below.  thanks

Comment: try window.location = "/"

Comment: What is the purpose of reloading the page? Generally the idea of using an ajax call is to _avoid_ loading a new page.

Comment: unless the page gets some data on load, and that ajax call changes this data, thus a reload would be needed to refresh the page with the new data view

Comment: Yes, Basem said exactly whats happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to refresh the current page, this should work:

```
window.location.reload()
```